# How to get back the 'Add <Shape Name>' menu after performing any other action?

Tags: interface

I would like to know how I can get back the 'Add ' menu which disappears after performing any action.

I tried <kbd>F9</kbd> key, <kbd>F6</kbd> key and <kbd>T</kbd> key which I knew after some Googling but they didn't dork.

I'm using Blender 2.80.

[image: Add <Shape Name>]

Comment: You just can't reopen this menu once you have modified the object.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not, you can just delete the object and re-add it though!